# Extract part of file name with multiple sections

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract part of a file name to compare with other file names as it is the only part that does not change. here is the pattern and an example

clearinghouse.doctype.payer.transID.processID.date.time
EMDEON.270.60054.1234567890123456789.70949996.20120925.014606403

all sections are the same length at all times with the exception of clearinghouse & doctype that can vary in character length.

The part of the filename that i need for comparison is the transID.

What would be the cleanest shortest way to do this in a shell script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, the easiest tool for simple tasks is the cut command.  Tell cut what character you want to use as a delemiter and which fields you want to print.  Here is the command that does what you want.

```
file=EMDEON.270.60054.1234567890123456789.70949996.20120925.014606403
transitId=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f4)
```

Awk can do the same thing, and allows you do much more complicated logic as well.

```
file=EMDEON.270.60054.1234567890123456789.70949996.20120925.014606403
transitId=$(echo $file | awk -F. '{print $4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the filename apart using the `read` command using an appropriate value
for `IFS`.

```
filename="EMDEON.270.60054.1234567890123456789.70949996.20120925.014606403"
IFS="." read clHouse doctype payer transID procID dt tm <<< "$filename"
echo $transID
```

Since you only want the transaction ID, it's overkill to assign every part to a specific variable. Use a single dummy variable for the other fields:

```
# You only need one variable after transID to swallow the rest of the input without
# splitting it up.
IFS="." read _ _ _ transID _  <<< "$filename"
```

or just read each part into a single array and access the proper element:

```
IFS="." read -a parts <<< "$filename"
transID="${parts[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a parameter expansion:

```
$ foo=EMDEON.270.60054.1234567890123456789.70949996.20120925.014606403
$ bar=${foo%.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*}
$ echo "${bar##*.}"
1234567890123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tranid==`echo file_name|perl -F -ane 'print $F[3]'`
```